# How do I filter the list based on comparision within list elements in Java 8?

Tags: collections, filter, java-8, java-stream

I have a

```
class MedicationPeriod {
    LocalDateTime startDate, endDate;
    //assume getters and setters
}
```

Then I have a `List<MedicationPeriod> medPrd = getMedPeriods();`

Elements in `medPrd` may have the same startDate.

Now I want to filter the list such that, for elements having the same startDate, the one with the greatest endDate should remain in the list. I.e. having the longest day.

**Example**: If list elements are:

1) startDate = 2018-Jan-1, endDate = 2018-Feb-25 // 25 days

2) startDate = 2018-Jan-1, endDate = 2018-Feb-20 // 20 days

3) startDate = 2018-Jan-5, endDate = 2018-Feb-25 // startDate is diff, we don't care

So the final list should have only elements 1) and 3). Element 2 will be removed since other MedicationPeriod with the same startDate has a greater endDate.

**Here is my attempt (non happily working) to get the result:**

```
mps.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(MedicationPeriod::getStartDate, e -> e, (a,b) -> a.endDate.isAfter(b.endDate) ? a : b)).values();
```

**My requirement:**

1. I want `List<MedicationPeriod>` not `Collection<MedicationPeriod>` as my solution gives `Collection<>`
2. I want to achieve this without collecting them and using `.values()` , because I may do further transformations while in streams and collecting them later.

Let's say I have to perform some test after filtering the MedicationPeriods and then collect it into:

```
class DateRange {
    LocalDate startDate, endDate;
}
```

How can I do this with only one terminal operation?

Comment: I think, it should be possible to replace `(a,b) -> a.endDate.isAfter(b.endDate) ? a : b)` with `BinaryOperator.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(MedicationPeriod::getEndDate))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code. It works. Just did a bit of refactoring

```
 new ArrayList<>(medPrd.stream()
          .collect(Collectors.toMap(MedicationPeriod::getStartDate, Function.identity(), (a, b) -> a.endDate.isAfter(b.endDate) ? a : b))
          .entrySet()
          .stream()
          .map(entry -> new DateRange(entry.getValue().startDate, entry.getValue().getEndDate())).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Incorporating @Holger 's suggestion it would look like

```
 new ArrayList<>(medPrd.stream()
      .collect(Collectors.toMap(MedicationPeriod::getStartDate, Function.identity(), BinaryOperator.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(MedicationPeriod::getEndDate))))
      .entrySet()
      .stream()
      .map(entry -> new DateRange(entry.getValue().startDate, entry.getValue().getEndDate())).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Comment: Thanks for refactor. How can i achieve this in intermediate stream operation. If i want to further transform this MedicationPeriod into DateRange and then collect into List<DateRange>. I want to have only one terminal operation.

Comment: How does DateRange class look like. I can edit my answer accordingly. Since you are getting a list, you can stream it and use map to transform. No rocket science required

Comment: Let's say DateRange is as follows: class DateRange{LocalDate startDate, endDate;} but don't transform this before collect :-)

Comment: sorry didn't understand. You can edit your question with these details

Comment: Updated my ansert. I don't think you can do this with one terminal operation(`.collect`). because you need to first decide which MedicationPeriods to take(which is possible only after you have traversed the stream once) and only after that you can create DateRange objects

Comment: I understand your answer. is there a way we can avoid using intermediary map and look for other strategy to solve a problem

Comment: whether we use map or some other data structure is if least significance here. But for the logic you need, you have to do a terminal operation and save it to some data structure and then move forward